# Video not play in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to play video on clicking a button. My AVPlayerViewController is open but not playing an video .Please help.

```
- (IBAction)btnPlay_Click:(id)sender {
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://player.vimeo.com/video/143506410"];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vimeo video you can use third party tools which helps you load  the vimeo video.

**Solution 1:** Please [try](https://github.com/tannauit/PlayVimeo) this, It works for me, just some lines of code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    vimeoHelper = [[VimeoHelper alloc] init];
    [vimeoHelper getVimeoRedirectUrlWithUrl:@"http://vimeo.com/52760742" delegate:(id)self];
}

- (void)finishedGetVimeoURL:(NSString *)url
{
    _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self presentViewController:_moviePlayerController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

**Solution 2:** [YTVimeoExtractor](https://github.com/lilfaf/YTVimeoExtractor)

May be it will help you.

Comment: They show me DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie fil

Comment: On which solution you are getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Use MPMoviePlayerController and add this line of code:

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://player.vimeo.com/video/143506410"];
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *player =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: videoURL];
 [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
 [player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Add one more line : [self.view addSubview: [player view]];

- movieController is an instance of MPMoviePlayerViewController declared in the .h file.
- [movieController.moviePlayer play] is not required and the player will start regardless if you didn't set autoplay to NO, but I observed that if you put play in it it starts a bit quicker. This could be just a coincidence.

**--------- If this is not working you can just do that following ----------**

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[player play];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

Comment: : Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x7fb3b151f4f0> on <ViewController: 0x7fb3b1616ba0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: MpoviePlayerViewControlle  deprected in iOS 9